# Generate objective c classes from XSD scheme like JaxB in Java?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa

I need to create iOS application which reads its configuration from local xml file.
Does iOS developers has similar framework to do it like JAXB in Java?
(JAXB generates Java classes from XSD scheme)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. There is [xsd2cocoa](http://code.google.com/p/xsd2cocoa/), but it is in very early phase. ALso, there is [XSD/e](http://www.codesynthesis.com/projects/xsde/). XSD/e does generate C++ code, which you can mix together with objective-c, but it is not the optimal solution either.

I assume both solutions imply too much overhead for "just" parsing config files.

Answer (score 0):

Try the myInotes app on the App Store, for iPad it has a simple parser generator in it. Just put myInotes in to the AppStore search for iPad and it should appear

Answer (score 0):

shameless plug : try my xsd2cocoa fork:
https://github.com/Daij-Djan/xsd2cocoa

it generates modern objC classes from XSD and also generates a parser based on livxml